# How to get rid of <Select a Value> from parameter when default value is already being used?

Tags: express, reporting-services, default

I have a drop down box called Grouping that has  written in it when it is grayed out, but my other drop downs don't have this. SSRS added the text by default. I want to remove it. The only way I think this is possible is to set a defult value for that paramter. But my problem is that I already have an expression in the default value, which states that if the previous parameter is null, then make the Grouping down down grayed out.

This is the expression in case of interest:

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!MyParameter.Value(0)), 1, 0)
```

Here is an illustration of the problem:

[image]

See how Grouping has the text in it even if it is grayed out, but the other drop downs do not?

How can I get rid of that text?

Comment: I haven't done anything like this before but it looks like you're only checking the first value of **MyParameter** with the (0) argument. Have you tried without it? `=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!MyParameter.Value), 1, 0)
`

Comment: @Hannover Fist, I removed the 0 and it still works. Looks like it's not needed. My problem still remains, however. <Select a Value> is still there when the box is grayed out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that worked for me.

1. Have NO default value for the parameter.
2. For Available Values, Specify Value.
3. Set Label to the string I needed. Set value to `=IIF(IsNothing(Parameters!MyParameter.Value(0)), 1, "String needed")`
4. Set additional values the same way but without expressions.